# Determine whether it's min or max of functional.

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

so I have such functional:
$$\phi(y)=\int\limits_0^1 (y^2+2y'^2+y''^2)dx, \ \ y(0)=y(1)=0, \ y'(0)=1, \ y'(1) = -\sinh1.$$

By using Euler-Lagrange formula, I get 
$$y^{IV} - 2y'' + y = 0$$
After solving I get:
$$y =  \sinh(x)(1-x).$$

And now, how to determine whether it's minimum or maximum, maybe local or not? I realize that I should check the second variation, but I saw there are some theorems. Can you give me simple steps how to check? Thank you.

Comment: $\phi$ is a convex function.